# Adding System.Web.WebPages dll to the reference (bin) gives error "Object is not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: iis, sharepoint, csrf, .net-4.8, antiforgerytoken

Adding System.Web.WebPages dll to the project reference for using System.Web.Helpers namesapce to validate Antiforgery token(AntiForgery.Validate())(bin) gives error "Object is not set to an instance of an object" when run the application

Adding System.Web.WebPages dll to the project reference for using System.Web.Helpers namesapce to validate Antiforgery token(AntiForgery.Validate())
Gives error "Object is not set to an instance of an object" when run the application

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Vague descriptions alone do not allow community members to understand the problem you are experiencing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to fix CSRF issue, i have added AntiForgery.Validate() method in the button click event.  To implement CSRF, I need System.Web.Helpers namespace which is in System.Web.WebPages dll, so it was also added in the reference. When I publish and deploy it to IIS, System.Web.WebPages dll was added to Sharepoint 80 bin folder. When I run the application, it shows an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.